# Trouble printing a generator expression as a list

Tags: python, list, binary-tree, generator

I am trying to return the values of all the leaves in a binary tree with a generator and putting the yielded values in a list. This is my recursive code that uses yield statements but I don't know how return the finals values with a generator. The second piece of code titled "Previous Code" shows the same code with print statements which outputs the correct values so the only issue is the generator. As a note, this code is using root.left and root.right imported from a Binary Tree class and seems to be working properly. Thank you in advance for any help!!

**My code**

```
        def leaves_list(self):
            def find(root):
                if not root:
                    yield
                if not root.left and not root.right:
                    yield root.data
                if root.left:
                    find(root.left)
                if root.right:
                    find(root.right)
            # my attempt
            a = find(self.root)
            lst = []
            for i in a:
                lst.append(next(a))
            return find(self.root)
```

**Previous Code**

```
    def leaves_list(self):
        def find(root):
            if not root:
                return
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                print(root.data, end = " ")
                return
            if root.left:
                find(root.left)
            if root.right:
                find(root.right)
        return find(self.root)
```

This is my tester code and should be returning the list `[5, 1, 8, 4]`.

**Tester Code**

```
root = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(3)
T = LinkedBinaryTree(root)
a = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(2)
a.parent = root
root.left = a
b = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(7)
b.parent = root
root.right = b
c = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(9)
c.parent = a
a.left = c
d = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(5)
d.parent = c
c.left = d
e = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(1)
e.parent = c
c.right = e
f = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(8)
f.parent = b
b.left = f
g = LinkedBinaryTree.Node(4)
g.parent = b
b.right = g

print(T.leaves_list())
```

Comment: This is hard to debug without the tree and node classes, but I'd observe that `lst.append(next(a))` should be `lst.append(i)`  As it is you are skipping every other value.

Comment: Are you doing this to practice generators, or are you just interested in getting the list? Because the straightforward generator version is inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues with your attempt:

- `find(self.root)` is called twice. This should not be necessary as it will do the work twice to get the same result again
- `lst` is created and populated but is never used. You should probably return it.
- Don't consume an iterator with both a `for` loop, and with repeated calls to `next()`. When you do so, you actually go to the next value *twice* in each iteration, thereby skipping a value in each iteration.
- Consider also that the standard `list` function already has this feature of creating a list from an iterator.
- In the `find` function you are doing nothing with the value(s) yielded by the recursive call. You should yield them also. You can use the `yield from` syntax for that.
- `if not root` will not work correctly when the tree really is empty, as the execution still continues after that `if` block, and so an exception will be raised. You need a `return` there.
- Also, when the tree is empty, there shouldn't be *anything* that is yielded. An iterator is allowed to just not yield anything, which is appropriate in that case.
- Not a problem, but since you have `if not root` as a base case, you don't really need to check for `None` before going left or right. So those `if` conditions can be removed, and the recursive calls can be made unconditionally.

Here is the corrected version:

```
    def leaves_list(self):
        def find(root):
            if not root:
                return
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                yield root.data
            yield from find(root.left)
            yield from find(root.right)

        return list(find(self.root))
```

Comment: That comment might be better placed at the question, since it is the Asker's subject.

Comment: I partially did, but then saw your answer's comprehensive list of issues and thought it might fit in there as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
# my attempt
a = find(self.root)
lst = []
for i in a:
     lst.append(i)
return lst
```

A shorter alternative:

```
# my attempt
return list(find(self.root))
```